I have mistakenly removed a package and not able to update or install any software in my desktop
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ noble: /etc/apt/keyrings/boot-repair.gpg != -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
   mQINBGYzoxcBEACurKKBm4hHDCALugw/YoZFfKRsFIKsK7u1kUWzAeA7RbJZbOro
   /bW6hjVZLCTCBMKT3LxTgcO04TcAiIcyJ9aavDLVbv8RtcyiCXVfB4qB8g5deZdE
   CRt0jJR6w8axzQVroqbmmkpr6Wxh3W/cDMw8YpXIWp6gj9YrvPdS+HGm2BZnatqU
   Or8sMeZ2CxRCGJ0jfTKcCfP9kuvxwxa6QZCqyi/fC2lpOKGVsHciJvvgAiKlzAN0
   7SHOtlsGr5BbL2nfNCjHbv99kfVV2XWgLaMpdB8nF5aBdhhLDCCUzPvN4gTQXNn2
   O/g+RrOmgrOsmHdzLazSK5c3aGb5LHFfDObKouQ6WjW6t+sfvtJg2UmrqOrb50r2
   DvZpmzR2BSAGVxKXNhSb0q0e4y93vBkPuTc8KgeEOkvrqaO1D+Vqy5stKTaO2XfC
   Had4JDCXuVFrKHDXp7rPB/X75JfFLU+xm93+dJR/n1+fo2cTSxi6NvMUquO8Kegt
   AxoH7E3duK3Pxau5QRIl4ahcxNMEgXRKrcqPsBiHpEqVKc0gHDKkQAEQHSGLmNl8
   hrLWBa3mClwpzac68JlT1J2D7ODX23pPr1uzxR5jZrhKHtHev1od1rPh2BtaXBKx
   aQYKujJz0oAPGOX7OyIBbhTz7iGyjXi/htZ8TwoXLbYXOMqERIh6G0BhfQARAQAB
   tBxMYXVuY2hwYWQgUFBBIGZvciBZYW5uVWJ1bnR1iQJOBBMBCgA4FiEEMIkBzDrR
   Wzq2TMDvPmhzZNLt218FAmYzoxcCGwMFCwkIBwIGFQoJCAsCBBYCAwECHgECF4AA
   CgkQPmhzZNLt21+chw/6AlexTCjc0F/Acjij8alawj+A3kOtZbvYTbFbMvM6aOEj
   tAvO7wo7fzPLjCfuKzv79+oP62Wb2iTjI1tkgwsHygntU3sYc+EE9MhQNLG4HQjA
   fBqDXcKLUe6nMoRw7etOiIMvcL2PJ9m3aDu1u7xRgdIS+SM+NABpY3THPNyF0Opk
   eC5PDAo1sSc0mJza/+yemHncb3eHUZZmyix7pn26q9mTSoHgcAKxTqL8SdjtzhKu
   xNHufbqpF45tcRMRkaViat3t5/sLI0R1nr1s4816iYrUP2vLmtiWMjoVi+OvUWZX
   r8AZkvL22PdkF8ltQ8u9YTpvPDu0p2wQJYnlMWOPNNWZ0AKM2vbeuGlqwvAmMQcb
   7UaK0tnN/oX45mAlpQBM1MJys+Q/hCPUsD+0LOszpRqx5gbTZb/SdThAdxtq/+Lj
   Ojhn/SKCn0JUUMLNrPo5iRAzWui3BO3MnMCqW9mGMKHGBOXlSIHBlAFmhlEtUTgK
   bKYtQAjnEvBE0OEW9S+Lm5IuioqqrU7WpSrwdZvFluCzax1ZVSH47sEZguRXuatD
   mmKLeLe3oH89XjMaFQ9LP+2ZmPD+zgosoZBRl610mKqO7FQz+KannfzXUgcxzF0l
   rS5isrksbA2h1IAWFETecbW55/UXZvmPlNwvs2AvOv47cDZC5IvoTKd+uoU/zRg=
   =ilP+
   -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
E: The list of sources could not be read.


enter image description here

Please edit your question and add the content of the .sources (or .list) file where the repo which causes the conflict is in.

more info required; you did not include the complete text display at the instance of the fault. This may be helpful: Open a terminal, type sudo apt update, hold CTRL, hit A, tnen Enter, hold CTRL+SHIFT, hit c, Edit the posting here, find the end, type <HR> and Enter. then hold CTRL+SHIFT and hit V - mark the pasted text and click { } above it.
